# Android - Facebook session CLOSED when using ParseFacebookUtils.logIn

Tags: android, facebook, session, parse-platform, parsefacebookutils

I am using Facebook and Parse SDK in  my Android app. I followed [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/authenticate) tutorial for Facebook login and authentication, changing between fragments for **login fragment** and **main menu fragment** depending on whether the session state is `OPENED` in the `Session.StatusCallback`. And the app works perfectly before integrating with Parse.

And now I encounter a problem. In the `onResume()` method of the main menu fragment, I added the following code.

```
final Session session = Session.getActiveSession();

if(session != null && session.isOpened()) {
    Request meRequest = Request.newMeRequest(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() {
    @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser graphUser, Response response) {
            if(session == Session.getActiveSession()) {
                // Check if the session is same as usual 
                ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(graphUser.getId(), session.getAccessToken(), 
                        session.getExpirationDate(), new LogInCallback() {
                    @Override
                    public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                        if (user == null) {
                            // The user wasn't saved.
                            System.out.println("User was not saved to Parse. ");
                        } else {
                            // The user has been saved to Parse.
                            System.out.println("User has successfully been saved to Parse.");
                            if (user.isNew()) {
                                // This user was created during this session with Facebook Login.                       
                                System.out.println("ParseUser created.");
                            } else {
                                // This user existed before.
                                System.out.println("User exists in Parse. Pull their values: " + user);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });     
            }
        }
    });
    meRequest.executeAsync();
}
```

So when the fragment is resumed and the Facebook session is opened, the Facebook user is added to the Parse database so that I can use `ParseUser` to `put` and `get` data afterwards. But the problem happens when using `ParseFacebookUtils.logIn()`, that it makes the Facebook session `CLOSED` and invokes the `Session.StatusCallback`, thus switching the visible fragment back to the login fragment.

I was dealing with this problem all day but cannot find a solution. I have added the code below in an [Application](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Application.html) but still not work.

```
Parse.enableLocalDatastore(this);
Parse.initialize(this, Application_id, Client_key);
ParseFacebookUtils.initialize(getString(R.string.facebook_app_id));
```

Is there a way to fix this? I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26787093/facebook-and-parse-sdks-on-android) but no quite good solution is provided. Thanks in advance!

Comment: The same seems to be true for any such facebook authentication including linking a facebook user to parse. The session returned by the Session class is null however, if the Facebook user has been linked to parse, then `ParseFacebookUtils.getSession()` is not.

Answer (score 2):

I was trying to do the same thing today. I was using the facebook sdk's UiLifecycleHelper to do the facebook login, make the graph api request and add the user to Parse db. That is how it is done in the example you mentioned - which I think is a bit outdated.

ParseFacebookUtils handles the session and all we need to do is call the login method on it, make the graph api call, get user data like email and update the user field.

Here's some code:

```
private void parseFacebookLogin(){
        ParseFacebookUtils.logIn(this, PARSE_FB_LOGIN_CODE, new LogInCallback() {
            @Override
            public void done(ParseUser user, ParseException err) {
                if (user == null) {
                    Log.d(tag, "Uh oh. The user cancelled the Facebook login.");
                } else if (user.isNew()) {
                    Log.d(tag, "User signed up and logged in through Facebook!");
                    Request.newMeRequest(ParseFacebookUtils.getSession(), graphUserCallback).executeAsync();
                } else {
                    Log.d(tag, "User logged in through Facebook!");
                }
            }
        });
    }

GraphUserCallback graphUserCallback = new GraphUserCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) {
            if (user != null){
                getUserDataFacebook(user);
                Log.d(tag, response.toString());
            }
        }
    };

private void getUserDataFacebook(GraphUser user){
//get user data here
}
```

Check out Parse's docs on [Facebook login](https://www.parse.com/docs/android_guide#fbusers).

Let me know if this works for you.